# Permission usage in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

I need to be shure, that only my app can broadcasts intents to my IntentService. How do I make it using Android Permissions?

I see similar permission usage in gcm android library, but I not understand how it works.

Comment: "This attribute (android:exported) is not the only way to limit the exposure of a service to other applications. You can also use a permission to limit the external entities that can interact with the service (see the permission attribute)."  HOW TO USE PERMISSIONS FOR LIMIT ACCESS TO MY SERVICE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that any of your own app can use this service (multiple apps) but other can not, 
you will need to implement signature based permissions.

Declare your own custom signature permission

```
<permission android:description="string resource"
android:icon="drawable resource"
android:label="string resource"
android:name="string"
android:permissionGroup="string"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Then enforce this permission in your BroadcaseReceiver using

```
android:permission="string"
```

tag in your receiver or even you can do that in any other component like activity, etc.

Then in your other app which wants to access above feature, can declare using-permission in its manifest. 
Remember : your second app must be signed by same certificate to use your custom signature based permission.
Read more about permissions here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

> If you plan on using your service only locally (other applications do
>   not use it), then you don't need to (and should not) supply any intent
>   filters. Without any intent filters, you must start the service using
>   an intent that explicitly names the service class.

Just don't put any Intent filters in your manifest...